# Is there a way to apply decorators to Python data structures?

Tags: python

From what I got so far, decorators applies to callables(functions and classes).
Wondering if there is a way to apply a decorator to a dictionary?(It can be any data structure, in fact).
The problem I try to solve goes along the following lines:
I have a lot of dictionaries which, from time to time, might be valid or not.

I want to mark them with a *decorator-like* as shown in the skeleton bellow...:

```
class Data(object):

    def invalide(self):
        return False

    def valide(self, some_dict):
        return some_dict

@Data.invalide  
dict_1 = {...}

@Data.valide  
dict_2 = {...}

@Data.valide  
dict_3 = {...}
...
...
@Data.invalide
dict_n = {...}
```

...so, when I call `some_function(dict_x)`, it would know to do one thing or the other based on the `valide`, `invalide` marks.

### -------------Later on--------------------

I ended up implementing the following:

```
In [2]: class Data(object):
   ...:     
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def valide(self, func):
   ...:         #print "Data is valide."
   ...:         return func()
   ...:     
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def invalide(self, func):
   ...:         #print "Data is invalide."
   ...:         return False
   ...:     

In [3]: @Data.valide
   ...: def dict1():
   ...:     return {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
   ...: 
   ...: @Data.invalide
   ...: def dict2():
   ...:     return {"d": 4, "e": 4, "f": 6}
   ...: 
   ...: def run_funct(some_dict):
   ...:     return some_dict
   ...: 

In [4]: print(run_funct(dict1))
   ...: print type(run_funct(dict1))
   ...: 
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
<type 'dict'>

In [5]: print(run_funct(dict2))
   ...: print type(run_funct(dict2))
   ...: 
False
<type 'bool'>
```

Comment: Why would you use the `valide` or `invalide` decorator instead of just assigning `False` to the appropriate variables directly?

Comment: There are many reasons and it will take too long explain it here...

Comment: That sounds like you're ascribing a lot more magic to decorators than what they actually do. Decorator syntax does extremely little - sticking `@some_deco` over the definition of a function `foo` is equivalent to sticking `foo = some_deco(foo)` after the definition.

Comment: If you think your reasons for wanting to use decorators are so complex that you can't describe them here, then it's unlikely that decorators have enough complexity to support your complex motivations for wanting them.

Comment: Can you not just add an extra "valid" key to your dictionaries? You can make it the first key listed.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan: No, a closure is a function which is defined inside another function and which uses variables from the outer function. It has nothing to do with whether it takes or returns functions. Also, almost all decorators that take functions also return functions.

Comment: @user2357112 Ok...:) here is one scenario to explain why I need them this way. Imagine, that they are generated once with some keys and values. For some dictionaries data might not be available yet in some dB until at a later time(undetermined, later time). In the mean time, I just mark them with '`valid, invalide` and know to skip or involve them in some action based on their validity. And this is only one reason beside others..Cheers!

Comment: @friendlydog That was something I thought about too and it might be the backup solution. Let's see if someone has some elegant solution.

Comment: @flamenco: Yeah, it really sounds like you're misunderstanding decorators. Even if decorators could be applied to things other than functions, "marking" dicts with decorators this way would be exactly equivalent to assigning `False` to the ones marked with `invalide`. The decorator syntax doesn't come with some decorator-specific way of attaching additional metadata to decorated objects.

Comment: @flamenco: That's still not even close to doing what you want.

Comment: @user2357112 True, to some degree. But since, `dict` cannot be decorated what can I do but to go with a crossbreed solution.

Comment: The thing you ended up doing is an overcomplicated equivalent of just assigning a dict to `dict1` and `False` to `dict2`. `run_funct` doesn't even have anything to do with what the name says it does; it doesn't receive a function as an argument, and it doesn't run any functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122356/discussion-between-flamenco-and-user2357112).

Answer (score 0):

Decorators, to my knowledge, can only be applied to callables (functions, classes etc.)

If I was in your place, I'd probably separate the logic to decide between valid/invalid in its own function.

Answer (score 0):

you could cobble something together with properties and decorators:

```
def valid(func):
    return property(lambda self: func(self))
def invalid(func):
    return property(lambda self: False)

class A:
    @valid
    def dict1(self):
        return dict(a=4, b=5)
    @invalid
    def dict2(self):
        return dict(c=6, d=7)
```

usage would then be:

```
a = A()
a.dict1
a.dict2
```

i can't say i would recommend doing this, but it should meet your needs.